# Is Array Separable To Two List

Tags: java, array

The aim of the implementation is divide an array to two sub array which the total of the every sub array should be equal. If Array is dividable then method return `true` else return `false`.

For example:

This array can be dividable to two sub parts and each sub array sum is equal to 5.

```
int[] array = {4, 1, 1, 3, 1}; // true {4, 1} , {1, 3, 1}
```

This array can be dividable to two sub parts and each sub array sum is equal to 4.

```
int[] array1 = {5, 4, -5, 3, 1}; // true {5, 4, -5} , {3, 1}
```

This array can be dividable to two sub parts and each sub array sum is equal to 5.

```
int[] array2 = {3, 2, -5, 10}; // true {3, 2} , {-5, 10}
```

---

This array can not be divided.

```
int[] array3 = {10, 11, 15, 8}; // false
```

---

Looking forward to hear other approaches. Thanks.

**Code:**

```
public class SplitArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array = {4, 1, 1, 3, 1};
        int[] array1 = {5, 4, -5, 3, 1}; 
        int[] array2 = {3, 2, -5, 10}; 
        int[] array3 = {10, 11, 15, 8}; 

        System.out.println(  isSeparable(array) );
        System.out.println(  isSeparable(array1) );
        System.out.println(  isSeparable(array2) );
        System.out.println(  isSeparable(array3) );
    }

    private static boolean isSeparable(int[] array) {

        if (array.length == 0)
            return false;

        int sum = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
            sum += array[i];
        }

        if(sum % 2 == 1){
            return false;
        }

        int expectedSum = sum / 2;
        int tempSum = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
            tempSum += array[i];
            if(tempSum == expectedSum) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The aim of the implementation is **divide an array to two sub array** which the total of the every sub array should be equal. If Array is dividable then method return true else return false.

The aim is clearly not met by your code; you never actually *divide the array*. Either the requirements are incorrect, or the code is. At this point in time you should ask for clarification. Trust me: as an architect I know how things can quickly derail; requirements should be very precise. For one, you've now wound up with a class `SplitArray` that never splits the array.

Furthermore, the "separable" property is rather specific, which means it should be clearly described in the code using comments. Otherwise you'll look to your code later on, wondering what the heck it was supposed to do.

---

The strategy followed is correct and performant. I like that it doesn't use an doubles, and that it returns `true` or `false` whenever it can. That's very high level (C-programmers that have to worry about resource allocation would not agree, but for Java it's OK).

---

```
System.out.println(  isSeparable(array) );
```

Don't use manual formatting of code, just use:

```
 System.out.println(isSeparable(array));
```

If the code becomes too hard to read, create a local variable and print that.

---

```
private static boolean isSeparable(int[] array) {
```

Probably not part of this exercise, but normally you'd create a `int separableIndex(int[] array)` and a constant `NOT_SEPARABLE = -1`. That way you don't just know that it is separable or not, but you can also decide to perform the actual split later. If you allow negative values then it should be named `firstSeparableIndex` or return an entire list of indices, whichever is required (e.g. `{-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1 }` can be split in two ways).

---

```
    if (array.length == 0)
        return false;
```

Always use braces in `if`. What you are saying here is that you cannot split an array in two if it is empty. However, are you sure that you've caught the boundaries right? Can `{ 0 }` be split into an array of 1 and an empty array? What about `{ 1, -1 }`? Doesn't this method always return `true` as long as the array contains elements? The problem here is that you use the division to check for correctness. If you would only allow two or more elements then you'd be alright.

If this was part of a library you may even have to consider the number of bits and two-complement implementation of `int`, otherwise you may overshoot `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or even go round-robin. I guess that's taking it too far for this exercise though.

**Always check your boundary conditions**.

---

```
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
```

Please use more whitespace or perform a code cleanup / run a formatter before sharing your code (you are **now** sharing your code!).

---

```
int sum = 0;

if(sum % 2 == 1){
    return false;
}
```

The whiteline here is distracting, especially since you've so nicely kept the lines together with the `for` loop later on.

Please see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51998794/589259) if you want to consider negative values. And yeah, why not create an `isEven` or `isOdd` function?

Finally, for this simple exercise we can immediately understand why you return `false`, but generally if we can only grasp *what* you are doing and not *why*, then you have to indicate the *why*.

```
// sub-arrays of integers can not add up to a fraction
```

or something along those lines.

---

```
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
```

Again the whitespace. Please keep to Java coding conventions.

But you're also overshooting: you could and probably should go to `array.length - 1` here so that you know that the final array will have at least 1 element in it.